# All objects have the same name

Tags: c, graph, strtok

I'm doing my final project for my algorithms course in C.  For the project, we have to take an input text file that contains lines like:

```
P|A|0
```

or

```
E|0|1|2
```

The former indicates a vertex to be added to the graph we're using in the program, the 2nd token being the name of the vertex, and the last token being its index in the vertices[] array of the graph struct.

I've got a while loop going through this program line by line, it takes the first token to decide whether to make a vertex or an edge, and then proceeds accordingly.

When I finish the file traversal, I call my show_vertices function, which is just a for-loop that prints each name (g->vertices[i].name) sequentially.

The problem is that where the name should go in the output (%s), I keep getting the last "token1" I collected.  In the case of the particular input file I'm using it happens to be the source node of the last edge in the list...which is odd because there are two other values passed through the strtok() function afterward.  The line in the file looks like:

```
E|6|7|1
```

which creates an edge from indexes 6 to 7 with a weight of 1.  The edge comes up fine.  But when I call any `printf` with a %s, it comes up "6".  Regardless.

This is the file traversal.

```
fgets(currLn, sizeof(currLn), infile);
maxv = atoi(currLn);
if(maxv = 0)
{
    //file not formatted correctly, print error message
    return;
}

t_graph *g = new_graph(maxv, TRUE);

while((fgets(currLn, sizeof(currLn), infile)) != NULL)
{
    token1 = strtok(currLn, "|");
    key = token1[0];

    if(key == 'P' || key == 'p')
    {
        token1 = strtok(NULL, "|");
        if(!add_vertex(g, token1))
        {
            //file integration fail, throw error!
            return;
        }
        //***If I print the name here, it works fine and gives me the right name!****
        continue;
    }
    if(key == 'E' || key == 'e')
    {
        token1 = strtok(NULL, "|");
        token2 = strtok(NULL, "|");
        token3 = strtok(NULL, "|");
        src = atoi(token1);
        dst = atoi(token2);
        w = atoi(token3);

        if(!add_edge(g, src, dst, w))
        {
            //file integration fail, throw error
            return;
        }
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        //epic error message because user doesn't know what they're doing.
        return;
    }
}
```

If I run `show_vertices` here, I get:

```
0. 6  
1. 6  
2. 6  
etc...
```

Comment: There's a lot of it, and I'm not really sure what would be relevant to post here.

Comment: This not clear enough. What does token mean by the way?

Comment: What @Dhaivat said, though some (not me) may object to his wording, is correct. We can't help you without seeing some of your code. However, try to avoid just dumping all of your code on us. Try to narrow it down to a minimal example that demonstrates the same errors/problems that you're experiencing. You might be able to solve it yourself that way, and if you can't we'll certainly have a much easier time helping you.

Comment: @btzmacin: I'm sorry, but I really think you've done a poor job of asking your question. For starters, about 90% of it really doesn't seem relevant to the specific problem. And second, you haven't shown enough information for anyone to resolve the issue. Isolate the code that causes the problem, in a new project if needed. And include the relevant snippet here along with the expected and actual results.

Comment: How about at least the code that's assigning values to `g->vertices[i].name`?  What if you use `%p` to print the address?  Are all names pointing to the same address?  Is `.name` an array of bytes or a pointer?  If a pointer, do you `malloc` memory for it?

Comment: I'd follow @tomlogic's line of thinking. If all your vertices end up with the same name, then it's likely that they *are* all the same objects (sharing memory, typically). Also, what's with the name of this question? This has nothing to do with printf.

Comment: seems like you are adding the edges to the vertice list where you should be adding just the vertices to that list and not the edges. So whenever you see P|A|0 you should be adding those to the vertice list and when you see E, it should just be a weight edge. May have to see the add_vertex and add_edge code.

Comment: @mgiuca  I had the exact same idea, so I did a bit of carpet-bombing and had a printf("%s\n", g->vertices[i].name) right after I add the vertex...it's got the right name at that point.

Comment: add_vertex is the one that adds the name to the next NULL index in the vertices[] array.  Add_edge simply inserts the weight at the right place in the adjacency matrix.  When I want to show edges (which works perfectly, btw) I just do a 2d traversal of the AM and extrapolate info from there.  Saves me from having to manage the matrix AND an edges array...and it's how our professor told us to do it.

Comment: @btzmacin, That's fine, you are using an adjacency list. It seems your edges are touching the name pointer, can you post your add_edge and add_vertex functions.

Comment: Not related to the question, but _please_, indent your code. It makes it much easier to read for both us and you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't copying the name.  So you end up with a pointer (returned by `strtok`) to single static array in which you read each line.  Since the name is always at offset 2, it that pointer will always be `currLn+2`.  When you traverse and print, that will be the last name you read.

You need to `strdup(token1)` before passing it to (or in) `add_vertex`.

No there isn't enough information to be certain this is the answer.  But I'll bet money this is it.

Comment: yea this is what i was thinking. I've made this mistake before :(

Comment: so instead of add_vertex(g, token1)...I should do add_vertex(g, strdup(token1)) ?

Comment: MY PARENTS AND MY GPA THANKS YOU!

Comment: @btzmacin LOL, we knew this because we've all done it (at least I have).  @Matt, I could see everyone in the comments was on the right track.  (@mgiuca pretty much nailed it.)  I thought maybe you were trying to not just give the answer because it was homework, but really the idea is to not *do* the homework for someone.  If I was sitting with him in the lab, I'd just show him what was happening in the debugger.  My guess is, after all this, he'll remember the pattern and be able to debug it if he does it again.

Comment: @btzmacin: Your add_vertex() function should be copying token1.  You could either have `.name` be an fixed-length array of chars (best choice) or malloc the memory as needed (extra work and you need to free it later).  If you want to thank @andrewdski, be sure to accept this as the answer to your question and upvote the helpful comments!